# (PYTHON) Until a == b

Tags: python, equals, repeat

Of course there is a way, but I'm unaware of it. Can anyone enlighten me on how to run a certain line of code over and over until one variable is equal to another. Basically I'm writing a simple program that randomly generates two numbers, and wont stop until both numbers are equal to each other. I know, it's just a simple, pointless program, but knowing this will help me further in programming.

Thanks!

Comment: you were looking for a [while loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop) (with negated loop condition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's one way

```
n1 = 0
n2 = 1
while n1 != n2:
    n1 = my_random_function()
    n2 = my_random_function()
```

or

```
while True:
    a = random_function()
    b = random_function()
    if a == b:
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

do

```
while a != b:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks, but someone else beat you to it, so I'm giving him/her the answer. Still voted your's useful!